# Using spinlocks with gcc

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-12.04, spinlock

how can I use pthread_spinlock_t in gcc 4.6.3?
Which flags do I have to specify at compile time?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the option `-pthread` or `-lpthread` when linking.

Options `-std=c99/c11` will restrict the available library functions to those of C99/C11 standard library

For getting C99/C11 languages features/library **and** and POSIX (and some BSD and some GNU extension) APIs, one can use `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11` option to GCC.

Comment: Looks like it's not working, I get " error: unknown type name ‘pthread_spinlock_t’ ".
I had to add -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L. Was hoping for a better way without having to use this macro define.

Comment: Did you have other options to GCC ? Like `--std=c99" ?

Comment: @Emanuele, because on Ubuntu 12.01.1 LTS with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, the `pthread_spinlock_t` and related functions do not need any gcc command line options by default.

Comment: I had the option -std=c99. Should I use another one? Whitout this option I can't declare variables around the code and in the for loops...

Comment: You can also use `--std=gnu99` instead.

Comment: Please specify this in the answer, so I can vote it up and close it! Cheers! :-) Ps. Ofc it works like a charm!

Comment: See also: [How to compile a C program that uses pthread.h?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420722/how-to-compile-a-c-program-that-uses-pthread-h/443607#443607)